# Is it possible to pseudo VPN a website through your own domain

Tags: vpn, website

This one is kinda hard to explain but here is a scenario that might help

So in the office Social media websites are blocked and you really want to chat with your Facebook messenger friends (let target just one site), A VPN might do the trick but let not use that route. You have a private server that is hosting your domain www.mydomain.com. And your domain is not blocked by the office. So you came up with the idea to "pseudo vpn" messenger. When you go to your domain wwww.mydomain.com the contents will be liked your in www.messenger.com but the url is still mydomain.com. You are still able to login and chat.

you dont mind security since you own the server so you know whats in there. And if they find you out your messenger account will not be found because they will still need to log-in (hopefully)

Is this scenario possible? and what do you call this so that i can research it further?

Comment: Advising folks how to bypass work security is off topic, sorry.  https://superuser.com/help/on-topic explicitly states not to answer questions for  _issues specific to corporate IT support and networks,_

Comment: @K7AAY i do not have any malicious intent with this question. Would it be okay if i change the scenario but with the same concept? I do not think it fits in that category

Comment: No, it won't help, because we know what you're doing.